# How to get last id number in console.log?

Tags: ajax, laravel-5.4

When I click submit I get this message.

> ReferenceError: input is not defined

How to get last id number in console.log when I create a new data and click on save or submit button?

Controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    if($request->ajax()) {
        $school = new SchoolsList();
        $school->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
        $school->province_id = $request->province_id;
        $school->city_id = $request->city_id;
        $school->center_id = $request->center_id;
        $school->save();

        return response()->json(['data_school' => $request->all(), 'id' => $school->id]);
    }
}
```

Ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#schools").submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        data_school = input.value;
        province_id = $('#province_id').val();
        city_id = $('#city_id').val();
        center_id = $('#center_id').val();
        $.post("{{ route('schools-list.store') }}", {province_id:province_id, city_id:city_id, center_id:center_id}, function (data_school) {
            console.log(response.data_school.id), function (response) {
                console.log(response.data_school.id);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your JavaScript you have "data_school = input.value;"

`input` is not defined and also not needed.

just remove that.

Also the last line of code `console.log(response.data_school.id)` is wrong. You set your own data structure, which is response.id

Comment: How to replace it now?